# Socket.io packets get lost between dis- and reconnect

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am using socket.io for connecting a smartphone (in a webframe) to a server and sending a few messages around (a few short strings per minute, nothing big). Since smartphones often tend to have an unsteady connection, socket.io is forced to reconnect every now and then. It does this automatically and the messages I want it to send after it noticed that the connection is currently unavailable are buffered and sent as a bundle once the connection is reestablished. So basically it's all going well with socket.io.

But when I send a message right before socket.io notices that the connection is gone, the message is lost. It can not be transmitted, but it does not get buffered by socket.io, either. I am quite content with socket.io, but this problem is bugging me, since I do not send many messages, but I really need those I DO send to be sent reliably. While the connection is established, all messages get transmitted perfectly, so I do not need to check for that. Only the second between the connection loss and socket.io noticing it is the critical moment where I face packet loss.

I have been thinking about mimicking TCP behaviour with sequence numbers and ACKs but it feels a bit like shooting ants with a rocket launcher. So my question is: Does anyone have a lightweight solution for this problem or even encountered it himself? I do not even ask for explicit code - I can do that myself - but a concept or something like that to get rid of this specific problem would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just log every message to database?
And use socket.io acknowledge option to make it even better.

from http://socket.io/#how-to-use
SERVER

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
    fn('woot');
  });
});
```

CLIENT

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect(); // TIP: .connect with no args does auto-discovery
  socket.on('connect', function () { // TIP: you can avoid listening on `connect` and listen on events directly too!
    socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
      console.log(data); // data will be 'woot'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I really did not think of this nice option for acks (I guess I will implement it in my current fix), but it would only have provided a partial solution anyway. This only handles successfull acknowledgements and I would still have had to make sure myself that the message gets resent if it did not arrive which I do not see a function for here.

Comment: yes, but at least you know they didn't get it and you have it stored ready to resend.

Comment: Actually I don't, since - as far as this looks - the callback only gets called when the message DOES get acknowledged which is actually the opposite of what I would like to have. Finding out that the message was not received (using my own timeout), storing and resending the message would still be something I'd have to do for myself. But thanks anyway, this feature is certainly a better way of sending acks than the way I currently do it :)

Comment: I understand your point but I prefer this way than creating another mechanism that will most certainly do the same but just different solution. If you find anything that does the reverse way (inform that it didn't receive the message) please tell me.

Comment: By the way, your client doesn't know if the other client received, but the server knows certainly. The server can store your message when it is sent to others and if the other one timeout or disconnect it can tell the sender that it failed

Answer (score 0):

If it is that important, I probably would mimic a naive version of TCP. Simply store a buffer client side and have the server respond to acknowledge the message, else send again from buffer.

Comment: Thank you. I did indeed implement it this way now, in addition to a feature that makes sure the server does not process the same message twice if it gets resent although he already got it before (which might be just as dangerous).